# Unable to display JSON values in an ASP.NET MVC partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, partial-views

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. This app interacts with a third-party REST service. I pass the service the names of some properties. For instance, "property1,property2". The service returns some JSON that looks like this:

```
"results":{
  "property1Type":"Collection",
  "property1":[
    {"found":3,"name":"Toys"}
  ],
  "property2Type":"Collection",
  "property2":[]
}
```

I am trying to print out the `found` and `name` values for each property in an ASP.NET Partial. Currently, I have the following in my view:

```
@foreach (var propertyName in Model.PropertyNames)
{
  var response = Model.Response[propertyName];
  Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_Result.cshtml", response);
}
```

The `PropertyNames` property is a list of the property names that I passed to the service (i.e. "property1, property2"). The `Response` property is a `JObject` I parsed from the returned JSON.

This code works so far. My problem is in _Result.cshtml. My code for that looks like this:

```
@if (Model.HasValues) {
  <div>@Model.Values("name")</div>
  <div>@Model.Values("found")</div>
  <div>@Model</div>
} else {
  <div>nothing</div>
}
```

When this code executes, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Additional information: No overload for method 'Values' takes '1' arguments

When I look at the `JArray.Values` method, I see two overloads. 1 that accepts an `object` as a parameter. And 1 that accepts no parameters. For that reason, the error doesn't make sense to me. If I remove the calls to `@Model.Values`, the `@Model` call runs fine and prints out:

```
[ { "found": 3, "name": "Toys" } ]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I print out the values for found and name in my partial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to use .Value() instead of .Values()?

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm

The error is correct, in that .Values() does not take any arguments.

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Values__1.htm

```
<div>@Model.Value("name")</div>
<div>@Model.Value("found")</div>
```